# Is there a way to push NamepaceMappings programmatically from the WCF host?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, wcf, .net-4.0

I have a WCF service that requires me to add the folowing to `Reference.svcmap`

```
<NamespaceMappings>
  <NamespaceMapping TargetNamespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.DirectoryServices" 
                    ClrNamespace="System.DirectoryServices" />
</NamespaceMappings>
```

If I don't have that line I get the following error:

```
Warning 1   Custom tool warning: Cannot import wsdl:portType
Detail: An exception was thrown while running a WSDL import extension:
 System.ServiceModel.Description.DataContractSerializerMessageContractImporter
Error: ISerializable type with data contract name 'DirectoryServicesCOMException' 
  in namespace 'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.DirectoryServices' 
  cannot be imported. The data contract namespace cannot be customized for
  ISerializable types and the generated namespace 
  'DomainManagement.Console.UserManagementProxy' does not match the required CLR 
  namespace 'System.DirectoryServices'. Check if the required namespace has been 
  mapped to a different data contract namespace and consider mapping it 
  explicitly using the namespaces collection. 
XPath to Error Source: 
 //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://example.com/v1']/wsdl:portType[@name='IUserManagement']
```

I also know having a common DLL between the client and server will also solve the issue but I do not want to have to require any client to also have the accompanying DLL to communicate with the service.

I understand the issue, and the fix (both dll and editing the file). What I would like to know is: Is there anything I can do on the Host side so every client that subscribes to this service does not need to any extra configuration of the service after generating the proxy in visual studio? (i.e. Using `SvcUtil` and using the `/n:http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.DirectoryServices,System.DirectoryServices` parameter is not a preferred option)

Comment: How would you know what the client namespace(s) should be?

Comment: @drozzy In the text of the error it already knows where it should be mapping "*ISerializable type with data contract name 'DirectoryServicesCOMException' [...] cannot be imported. The data contract namespace cannot be customized for ISerializable types and the generated namespace 'DomainManagement.Console.UserManagementProxy' does not match the required CLR namespace 'System.DirectoryServices'*". I just find it annoying that for every program I write that consumes this service I must remember to manually go in and paste the 4 lines of code in to `Reference.svcmap` before it works.

Comment: Oh boy, this is way beyond my understanding! My projects are much simpler, but I don't use svcutil (probably because I'm just starting out). I really don't see the problem though in sharing the contracts interfaces with the client, as in: http://www.dnrtv.com/default.aspx?showNum=122  P.S.: Sorry for sidetracking :(

Comment: The error is complaining that it doesn't know how to serialize type "DirectoryServicesCOMException". Are you passing one of these types as a parameter or return value in your service operations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is simply down to the fact that some types "don't serialize well". Trying to pass a NameValueCollection across WCF (prior to VS2010) produced exactly the same error as you are seeing, despite it being serializable. Another one that I've seen crop up from time to time is the SqlException ([see here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/e5356dcd-0097-43fb-b36e-aa26f34bc45c/)).

Alas I'm not aware of any server-side solutions. I find that providing clients with a "service interface" DLL to be the cleanest approach - it avoids having to generate client-side code via svcutil/add service reference, but you seem to have your reasons for not doing this. The alternative would be to refactor your server-side code to avoid passing around a `DirectoryServicesCOMException`. You could try Googling the "NameValueCollection WCF serialization" issue and see if any of the suggested workarounds from back then might be applicable to your scenario. I suspect not though, as this was caused by the way it implemented certain interfaces internally.

Comment: Having troubles with SqlException, solution? change my service and receive just text !